# Example for a space that is contractible to precisely one of its points

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Give an example for a space that is contractible to one of its points and is not contractible to another of its points.

I am really curious about that space, I have thought about tree with $n$ vertices but It doesn't seem to work also maybe it is true for comb space or zigzag space but it is just a feeling, so please help me. Thank you very much.

Comment: How about the union of the set of lines in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with rational slope?

Comment: it is contractible to the origin, how should I show that it is not to another point,imagine that all line come to origin except one line,then we can compress to any point in that line,if I am wrong please tell me,it was just something in mind.

Comment: imagine a small open ball around some point on that line which doesn't contain the origin, that ball no matter how small it is will also contain other lines, so the map you described can not be continuous.

Comment: that was great,really thank you,you have learned me a good point of view.

Comment: I've written up an answer with a few more details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The comb space works although any point on the 'base line' can be deformation retracted to so depending on the interpretation of your question, this might not quite fit your criteria. Instead, we can take a space which is morally the comb space but where we quotient out by the subset of points which can be deformation retracted onto. I believe (though I have not checked) that this space is homeomorphic to the intersection of the unit disk with the union of the set of lines through the origin in the plane with rational slope. Ofcourse, we don't need to take the intersection of this set of lines with the disk, so we could have just taken the set $$\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}\mid y=\alpha x, \alpha\in\mathbb{Q}\}\cup\{(x,y)\mid x=0\}.$$

This space only has a single point which can be deformation retracted onto and that is the origin. Any other point has all neighbourhoods containing points on lines which the prescribed point does not lie on, and so any attempt to deformation retract the space to this point must at some point break continuity (this can be made more precise but hopefully the intuition is clear).

Comment: thank you very much for your explanations.they are so useful.